# How can you display an image with ListAdapter in a listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I want to be able to display images within a listview using ListAdapter.

Currently below I'm passing strings called **TAG_COUNTRY**, they are image file names for example ireland.png, usa.png for example.

The image string file names appear in my listview in a column, but i need to actually show the images not the file name. Im confused whats the best approach to take here.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), inboxList, R.layout.pga_list_item,
                        new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_COUNTRY, TAG_FROM, TAG_DATE, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_SUBJECT },
                        new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.pic, R.id.subject, R.id.date, R.id.mail, R.id.roundscore }) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have use a custom `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter`. [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) is a good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for that Piyush, i was hoping for an easier solution but its never easy with android :)